# Require Workbench Reviewer field

Tags: 9, workflows

For the project i'm working on, I am using [content moderation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-moderation/overview) and [workbench_reviewer](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_reviewer) modules. This allows content authors to choose a reviewer (manager) for the next step in the publishing workflow who then receives an email.

The only issue is that by default the workbench reviewer module doesn't have an option to make the field required. For my project I need to make this a required field.

I have tried adding the below to hook_form_alter() but it doesn't seem to work for this field.

`$form['workbench_reviewer']['#required']=TRUE;`

I would very much appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes the top-level form items are containers for child items that are the actual form fields. You may need to dig a little deeper into `$form['workbench_reviewer']` to find the input element and mark it required there.

Comment: Thanks @sonfd I was able to set with `$form['workbench_reviewer']['widget']['#required']=TRUE;`